# Image in JFrame doesn't want to display with the call in another class

Tags: java, image, swing, display

I work on a Java development software with Swing and I have a problem with my code, I want to display an image with the LoadingFrame class, its main work but when I call the constructor and the start() method in my main class, the frame opens but the image doesn't display (I have no Exception).
Why it doesn't work with my main class?

```
public class LoadingFrame
{
    private  JFrame frame;

    public LoadingFrame()
    {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setSize(800, 600);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);               
        frame.setUndecorated(true);

        frame.setContentPane(new Panneau());   
    }
    public void start()
    {
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void stop()
    {
        frame.setVisible(false);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        LoadingFrame l = new LoadingFrame();
        l.start();
        try
        {
            Thread.sleep(3000);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        l.stop();
    }
}

public class Panneau extends JPanel
{
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        System.out.println("hello");

        try 
        {
          Image img = ImageIO.read(new File("Images/loading.png"));
          //g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, this);
          //Pour une image de fond
          g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight(), this);
        } 
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The App class is my main class :

```
public class App {
//Attributes used to display the application
    private JFrame frame;

//Attribute which display a waiting frame
    private static LoadingFrame loadingFrame;

/**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    loadingFrame = new LoadingFrame();
                    loadingFrame.start();

                    App window = new App();

                    loadingFrame.stop();

                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } 
                catch (Exception e) 
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

/**
     * Create the application.
     */
    public App() 
    {
        initialize();
        synchronizeScriptReferenceList();
        synchronizeTests();
    }
[...]
}
```

Comment: Why do you call `loadingFrame.stop()` almost immediately after calling `loadingFrame.start()`? On top of this, `App window = new App();` will do almost nothing relevant. The `loadingFrame` is static, and run in a static context, so you don't need an `App` object for this example.

Comment: Also, you never call `.pack()` on the frame, or something similar

Comment: Hello, it's normal, the constructor App called after start() is long to execute (maybe 2 minutes, it's a synchronize process with many files)

Comment: 1) See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556) 2) That paint method is wrong. It thould not be loading images, and should immediately call the super method.

Comment: Also, you open an Image everytime you want to draw. That __KILLS__ performance

Comment: Yes, i forgot .pack() but when I add this line, I have the same result

Comment: @DamienRamat Where did you put it?

Comment: I put it, in my start() method, just before setVisible(true).

Comment: @DamienRamat As the very first line in `paintComponent`, call `super.paintComponent`, I think I remeber that being very important

Comment: Also on the `g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight(), this);` line, try changing `this` to `null`

Comment: I try to add `super.paintComponent` at the first line in paintComponent, but it dosn't work. It's the same when I change `this` to `null`

Comment: In fact, when I added `.pack()` in the `start()` method, the main of LoadingFrame doesn't display the image, like when I call `start()` in the App class.

Comment: @DamienRamat does the LoadingFrame `main` work?

Comment: @TheTromboneWilly Actually `this` is correct.  Passing `null` is incorrect and should never be done.

Comment: When I delete `frame.pack()` yes!

Comment: The print message "Hello" is displayed. So, We passed in the `paintComponent(Graphics g)`method;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to get this to work from `App.java`. For some reason, using `EventQueue` isn't cutting it. I tried to use `SwingUtilities` as well, but that doesn't work either. Finally I tried just get rid of the Thready-stuff in `App.main` at just straight up running it in the main thread. For some reason, this works when the other approaches do not! Here is my code:

```
// In the App class: 

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        loadingFrame = new LoadingFrame();
        loadingFrame.start();

        App window = new App();

        loadingFrame.stop();

        window.frame.setVisible(true);
    } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

When I used this code, I got it to work! (for some reason unknown to me), And here's a bonus rewrite of the `Panneau` class:

```
class Panneau extends JPanel
{
    Image img;

    public Panneau() {
        try
        {
            img = ImageIO.read(new File("Images/loading.png"));
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), this);
    }
}
```

There are two main difference with this class; problems which I addressed. Here they are:

1. I call `super.paintComponent` as the very first method in our own `paintComponent`
2. I only load the loading image once, in the constructor, and not every single time I want to draw, which moves everything along much smoother. (you don't want the loading screen to be CPU heavy, do you?)

Hopefully, with these improvements, I hope you can make your program work! It worked with me, so I wish the best of luck to you.

P.S. Don't call `frame.pack()`, that was a mistake on my part. For some reason, I think it doesn't work well with undecorated windows.

Comment: Thanks for your response, yes it's work with the `main` of  `LoadingFrame.java` but it doesn't work with the App class, and that is my problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's work, I don't understand why it's work when we delete `EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable(){ public void run() {` but it's cool :D

Comment: @DamienRamat Same here, dude, I'll maybe research later why this happens. It's a complete mystery to me!

Comment: Ok, ahh Java and its mysteries... ^^

Comment: `g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), null);` as mentioned by @VGR, this **should be** `g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), this);`. In future, please try reading the JavaDocs for these methods and understanding them. It seems the advice you are giving is a loose collection of 'tips' picked up around the internet. Some of the things people commonly say are useful, others are things people ***commonly** get wrong.*

Comment: @AndrewThompson http://s32.postimg.org/6rsjowtol/Screen_Shot_2016_05_18_at_3_50_15_PM.png look at the bottom

Comment: @TheTromboneWilly Look at the JavaDocs, like I instructed earlier. Tutorial code often takes 'shortcuts'..

Comment: @AndrewThompson I understand that `ImageObserver` can be useful in many cases, but here it just isn't necessary for a static loading screen...

Comment: *"but here it just isn't necessary"* And when the programmer expands the class to accept an image in the constructor, and the user passes an image that loads asynchronously, it will fail. Given it is robust using the `ImageObserver`, why code it ***any* other way?**

Comment: @AndrewThompson I did a little more researching and I figured out more about `ImageObserver`s. I edited my answer, and I think you have converted me to actually using these things! (at least with `Component`s)

Comment: *"(at least with Components)"* Yep. That's what I'm talkin' about. They have all the makings to use asynchronously loaded images, built in. :)